# SCSS Background Hover

Tags: html, css, sass, node-sass

I am struggling to change the background of my link when I hover over it with SCSS. I am able to do so when I go back into my main.css, but I really want to understand what I can't see with SCSS.

```css
%btn-shared {
 display:inline-block;
 padding: 0.8rem 2rem;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 border: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

.btn {
 &-main {
  @extend %btn-shared;
  color: #333;
  background: $main-color; 
  }
 &-light {
  @extend %btn-shared;
  color: #333;
  background: $main-color;
  }
 &-dark {
  @extend %btn-shared;
  color: #f4f4f4;
  background: $dark-color;
  }
}
```

Where do I implement the `:hover` ?

Comment: Your SCSS code is invalid. `&btn-shared` looks wrong, `@extend %btn-shared;` is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your selector `&btn-shared` is incorrect, I assume you meant to write a placeholder selector `%btn-shared`.
Then, if you want the same hover for all your buttons you can set it directly in `%btn-shared`:

```
%btn-shared {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0.8rem 2rem;
   transition: all 0.5s;
   border: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   
   &:hover {
     ...
   }
}

.btn {
   &-main {
      @extend %btn-shared;
      color: #333;
      background: $main-color; 
   }
   &-light {
      @extend %btn-shared;
      color: #333;
      background: $main-color;
   }
   &-dark {
      @extend %btn-shared;
      color: #f4f4f4;
      background: $dark-color;
   }
}
```

However, if you need a different hover for each type of button then you need to set it for each of them separately:

```
.btn {
   &-main {
      @extend %btn-shared;
      color: #333;
      background: $main-color;
      
      &:hover {
        ...
      }
   }
   &-light {
      @extend %btn-shared;
      color: #333;
      background: $main-color;
      
      &:hover {
        ...
      }
   }
   &-dark {
      @extend %btn-shared;
      color: #f4f4f4;
      background: $dark-color;
      
      &:hover {
        ...
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried these variations, but it still does not work. Could you think anything else that could be stopping this fro working?

Comment: @Neelam What does your compiled code look like? It may be a problem of specificity, or your code is not compiling properly, or a problem of cache... I can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
.btn {
     &-main {
      background: $main-color;
      &:hover {
        background: yellow; 
      }
     &-light {
      background: $main-color;
      &:hover {
        background: yellow; 
      }
      }
     &-dark {
      background: $dark-color;
      &:hover {
        background: yellow; 
      }
      }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add selector `&:hover` to inside placeholder selector `%btn-shared` for common `hover effect`. However, If you want different `&:hover` for each type of button then you need `&:hover` separately.

```
$main-color : #f6c13c;
$main-hover-color : #ab7a00;
$light-color : #cccccc;
$light-hover-color : #a2a0a0;
$dark-color : #555555;
$dark-hover-color : #000000;

%btn-shared {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.8rem 2rem;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 4px 12px #b9b9b9
    }
}
.btn {
    &-main {
        @extend %btn-shared;
        color: #333;
        background: $main-color;
        &:hover {
            color: #f4f4f4;
            background: $main-hover-color;
        }
    }
    &-light {
        @extend %btn-shared;
        color: #333;
        background: $light-color;
        &:hover {
            color: #f4f4f4;
            background: $light-hover-color;
        }
    }
    &-dark {
        @extend %btn-shared;
        color: #f4f4f4;
        background: $dark-color;
        &:hover {
            background: $dark-hover-color;
        }
    }
}
```